# DigiCert certificate not working with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ssl-certificate, digicert

Have generated the valid certificates from DigiCerts (CA file and the pem file) . PEM file is the combination of private key and server certificate. but somehow the mongo shell is not working with these certificates.

Here is the setup: 
The environment :

**what we have**

> Mongo server : Ubuntu 16.04 ,  mongo version : 4.0.10

have configured the `/etc/mongod.conf` file as well. mentioned the path of the Pem file and CA file correctly. the CN name matches the hostname and is exactly the same.

**what is the issue**

but now when i run the following mongo command , it fails

```
root@m1:/home/administrator# mongo --port 27017 --ssl --host m1.com –-sslPEMKeyFile /etc/pemfile.pem –-sslCAFile /etc/cafile.pem
```

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.13 connecting to:
>   mongodb://m1.com:27017/%E2%80%93-sslPEMKeyFile?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>   2019-12-05T06:50:31.195-0500 I NETWORK  [js] DBClientConnection failed
>   to receive message from m1.com:27017 - SocketException: short read
>   2019-12-05T06:50:31.195-0500 E QUERY    [js] Error: network error
>   while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'm1.com:27017'  :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17 @(connect):2:6 exception:
>   connect failed root@m1:/home/administrator#

the current server is primary/master server i guess.

please suggest

Comment: please suggest . i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution on this. The actual issue was , not having Trusted root certificate in the CA file. CA file was having just DigiCert CA certificate but TrustedRoot certificate was missing.

The moment i added the certificate , it started working. 
Thanks.